# Jogo em Löve não funciona após compilar

Tags: lua, löve

Recentemente, criei um jogo baseado no `löve`, que uma vez terminado e testado, resolvi tentar compilar.

Segui o [tutorial](https://www.love2d.org/wiki/Game_Distribution) da compilação da wiki do löve, usando:

```
copy /b love.exe+GhostShield.love GhostShield.exe
```

Ele compilou normalmente, mas quando executei o jogo compilado, me surgiu um problema inesperado:

> Error
>
> controllers/menuController.lua:8: attempt to compare number with nil
>
> Traceback
>
> controllers/menuController.lua:8: in function 'menuDisplay'
>   main.lua:180: in function 'draw'
>   [C]: in function 'xpcall'

Procurei a linha 8 que falhou:

```
menu.menuPresentation()
menu.menuButton(200,250,90,30,"Jogar")
menu.menuButton(500,250,90,30,"Como jogar")
if  ranking.readRanking() >= 200 then --Problema aqui
    menu.menuButton(350,350,90,30,"Extra")
end
menu.menuButton(350,500,90,30,"Sair")
```

E a função que ele recupera o valor do ranking:

```
ranking.readRanking = function ()
    rankingReader = love.filesystem.read(rankingLocal, love.filesystem.getSize(rankingLocal))
    return tonumber(rankingReader)  
end
```

O mais curioso é que posso arrastar a pasta para o ícone do löve ou comprimir ele em .zip e mudar a extensão para .love, e ele funciona perfeitamente, o erro só ocorre quando eu compilo em executável.

**Anotação:** Existe uma função para mudar a forma do mouse no começo do código, e o mouse muda corretamente, mesmo após o erro, então acredito que foi compilado corretamente.

Quando o programa inicia, eu faço uma verificação nele:

```
if not love.filesystem.exists(rankingLocal) then
    ranking.createRanking()
end
```

Teoricamente, fazendo isso, eu garanto que o arquivo exista, mesmo que a pasta padrão mude:

```
ranking.createRanking = function ()
    rankCreate = love.filesystem.newFile(rankingLocal)
    rankCreate:open("w")
    rankCreate:write("0000")
    rankCreate:close()
end
```

Um detalhe que achei interessante é que se eu executo o [meu jogo](http://www.mediafire.com/download/94u49hqpa3rb6v9/Ghost+Shield.rar) como "programa independente", ele falha, mas se arrastá-lo para ser executado na base do [`löve2d`](https://bitbucket.org/rude/love/downloads/love-0.9.0-win32.zip), arrastando-o até ele, funciona sem qualquer problema, tanto na versão instalada no sistema quanto na versão zipada...

Comment: Qual o valor de `rankingLocal`? Parece que no local onde você executa após compilar ele não consegue encontrar `rankingLocal` e acaba retornando nil.

Comment: @brasofilo: além de facilitar para quem quiser reproduzir o problema, não ter de ficar copiando manualmente o texto da imagem.

Comment: @LucasNunes No caso, `rankingLocal` está setado como "ranking.txt", e no caso ainda coloquei um teste pra confirmar que o arquivo existe, e adicionei um valor manualmente para testar. O mais curioso é que se eu não mudar nada, e executar como projeto, ele funciona sem problemas.

Comment: @brasofilo vou colocar as linhas com problemas

Comment: @Gammeth Outra explicação seria que, quando compilado, o executável utiliza outro diretório padrão, diferente daquele onde o .exe está. Assim "ranking.txt" não é encontrado. Você poderia compartilhar a versão compilada (se possível), para verificar isso.

Comment: Eu não sei se tem isso no `Löve`, mas se fizer `require('lfs')`, você pode ver qual é o diretório atual do executável com `print(lfs.currentdir());`. Daí dá para comparar das antes e após compilar.

Comment: @LucasNunes não sei se é possível requerermos as extensões do lua, pois uma vez tentei recuperar o iup e falhou tudo que eu tentei.

Comment: Quando executo aqui funciona normal. Eu realmente acho que o problema é com a definição do diretório padrão do programa. Mas, não pude testar.

Comment: @LucasNunes você poderia confirmar que o jogo criou o arquivo `ranking.txt` em `%appdata%/LOVE/Ghost Shield`?

Comment: Acho que consegui resolver. Mas o arquivo foi criado em `%appdata%/Ghost Shield/`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pelo que parece, o `löve` só escreve no diretório `%appdata%` (no caso do Windows), conforme está na [wiki](https://love2d.org/wiki/love.filesystem), onde você pode criar uma pasta para o seu projeto.

No entato, após compilar, o `löve` aparentemente não aceita mais a pasta padrão `%appdata%/LOVE/`, exigindo que você crie um própria pasta para seu projeto.

Para resolver isso, em `love.load()` acrescente a seguinte chamada:

```
 love.filesystem.setIdentity("Ghost Shield")
```

Essa função definirá que os arquivos que seu projeto criar serão escritos em `%appdata%/Ghost Shield/`.